# How to solve this Inverse Laplace Transform $\frac{s}{s^2-s+\frac{17}{4}}$

Tags: laplace-transform

How would I solve this Inverse Laplace transform?

$$\mathscr{L}_s^{-1} \left\{ \frac{s}{s^2-s+\frac{17}{4}} \right\}$$

The solution is
$$f(t) = (1/4 )e^{t/2} (\sin(2 t)+4 \cos(2 t))$$

I know I need to break up $F(s)$ into more common Laplace transforms, but I'm not quite sure how to begin.

Comment: Partial fractions, completing the square, or both.

Comment: Use the derivative property of Laplace transform to get the final result after partial fractions

Comment: Like Chappers said, complete the square in the numerator. You get

$$\frac{s}{(s - \frac{1}{2})^{2} + 4}$$

which hopefully looks familiar to you.

Comment: That was it! I can't believe I didn't see it. Thank you.

Comment: @Mattos, do you mean "denominator"?

Comment: @JoelReyesNoche Yeah I did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
F(s)&=\frac{s}{(s - \frac{1}{2})^{2} + 4}\\
&=\frac{\frac{1}{2}}{(s - \frac{1}{2})^{2} + 4} + \frac{s-\frac{1}{2}}{(s - \frac{1}{2})^{2}+ 4}\\ \\
f(t) &= (1/4)e^{t/2} (\sin(2 t) + 4\cos(2 t))
\end{align}
$$

<sub>Credit to Chappers, Oliver, and Mattos for guiding me to the above solution</sub>

Comment: ...accept yourself!